# Android, how to obtain state in activity from fragment

Tags: java, android

I am following the one activity/ many fragment approach for this application. From the picture, you can see there is a main activity with a toolbar spinner with sorting preferences. The option selected by the user will dictate how the recyclerView sort itself.

My question is, what is the best approach for fragment to obtain the information about what the user has selected in the toolbar spinner while keeping separation of concern?

Here is how the activity gets notified of user event in the spinner:

```
@Override
public void onSortMenuItemClicked(MenuItem id) {
    mFragmentScreenNavigator.swapToJobRequestFragment(mUserProfilePersistence.getUserProfile().getEmail());
}
```

Once the user has selected a sorting preference, I have a navigator that navigates to the recyclerView fragment

Basically, what I want to achieve is instead of 'telling' the fragment what the sorting preference is, is there a way for the fragment to 'go out' and get that information? thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: You also could check info about Rx or event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ViewModel` for the purpose of communication between Activity and Fragment. To make it work you also can use `LiveData` to observe for variable changes and updating if it happens.

1) Don't forget to add corresponding dependencies.

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
```

2) Create a class that extends from `ViewModel`. In this class, we have `MutableLiveData` object that allows up to work with `LiveData`. Probably it's better to use `Integer` type so you could change it like id.

```
public class ExampleViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<String> sortingMode = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<String> getSortingMode() {
        return sortingMode;
    }

    public void setSortingMode(String mode) {
        sortingMode.postValue(mode);
    }
}
```

2) Get a reference to your `ViewModel` inside Activity so you could update the value with sorting mode from (I believe) your options menu

```
ExampleViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ExampleViewModel.class);
```

3) To change the value you simply need to call your `ViewModel` method that will update the value o variable depending on item/id/title (whatever sounds better for you).

```
viewModel.setSortingMode("Example Mode");
```

4) Get the Activity `ViewModel` inside Fragment

```
ExampleViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(ExampleViewModel.class);
```

5) Subscribe to `LiveData` object to observe value changes

```
viewModel.getSortingMode().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(String s) {
        // Provide needed logic depending on sorting preferences
    }
});
```

It's just a little example of how it works. Architecture Components are really powerful so I strongly recommend you to read about it.

Result (Green sector is Fragment inside Activity, they both are observing):
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbjqy.png)